# Instancing with export variables not working, so, not able to clone scenes by adding other scenes as a child of the Main

Tags: instance, godot, gdscript

I am coding a star collect game in Godot, but while trying to add a scene as a child of the main (The scene which starts first, and the scene where I am doing the instancing), it's not working, rather the debug screen lags so much that it shows "Not Responding". I am coding in GDScript. Here's what I coded in the main scene to do the instancing:

```
extends Node2D

export (PackedScene) var Star

func _ready():
    pass

func _on_Timer_timeout():
    var star = Star.instance()
    add_child(star)
```

I've also inserted the desired scene I want to instance in the Script variables section (Sorry, as I'm new to Godot I'm not able to explain the terms well) :
[Script Variables section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ6NN.png)

And this is the code of the scene which I am instancing:

```
extends Area2D

export var done = 0
export var speed = 43
export var spinVal = 0
export var dir = 0

func _ready():
    done=0
    dir=5-(randf()*10)
    spinVal = 5-(randf()*10)
    position.x=randf()*10
    position.y=-20
    while done==0:
        position.y+=speed
        rotation_degrees=0+dir
        rotate(spinVal)
    print(position)


func _on_VisibilityNotifier2D_screen_exited():
    if (position.y<720):
            done=1
            queue_free()
```

Before, I had tried the simple way of instancing before I used PackedScene method, but I was facing the same problem. Now I'm trying it this way but no improvements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instancing is fine. Your scene is wrong.

As soon as you add the instanced scene with `add_child`, it's `_ready` will run. And this:

```
func _ready():
    done=0
    dir=5-(randf()*10)
    spinVal = 5-(randf()*10)
    position.x=randf()*10
    position.y=-20
    while done==0:
        position.y+=speed
        rotation_degrees=0+dir
        rotate(spinVal)
```

Well, that is is an infinite loop. The first line ensures `done` is 0. And nothing in there will set `done` to something else. The game is stuck there.

---

I see you set `done` somewhere else:

```
func _on_VisibilityNotifier2D_screen_exited():
    if (position.y<720):
            done=1
            queue_free()
```

Yet, that code never had a chance to run.

---

If you really, REALLY, want to write your motion in `_ready`. You can do this:

```
func _ready():
    done=0
    dir=5-(randf()*10)
    spinVal = 5-(randf()*10)
    position.x=randf()*10
    position.y=-20
    while done==0:
        yield(get_tree(), "physics_frame") # <--
        position.y+=speed
        rotation_degrees=0+dir
        rotate(spinVal)
```

When the code reaches `yield`, it will be suspended until the specified signal happens, then it continues. In this case the `"physics_frame"` signal of the `SceneTree`. *I'm using `"physics_frame"` instead of `"idle_frame"` given that this is an `Area2D`.*

---

The more idiomatic way to write this is, of course:

```
extends Area2D

export var done = 0
export var speed = 43
export var spinVal = 0
export var dir = 0

func _ready():
    done=0
    dir=5-(randf()*10)
    spinVal = 5-(randf()*10)
    position.x=randf()*10
    position.y=-20

func _physics_process(_delta):
    if done != 0:
        return

    position.y+=speed
    rotation_degrees=0+dir
    rotate(spinVal)

func _on_VisibilityNotifier2D_screen_exited():
    if (position.y<720):
            done=1
            queue_free()
```

In all honesty, I don't think you need `done` at all. However, given it is an exported variable, I didn't remove it.

*I'm not sure about your rotation either. But that is a separate issue.*